# Compare text and highlight differences in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Today i want to create a app in react-native that compare two string for first time it will be simple . For example

```
var str1 = "Hello there";
var str2 = "Hello";
```

I want to highlight a word that is different from the other text. And in example it is there. Something like online compare tools. So it will looks like
[image]

"There" word is with different background !

So i have no idea how to start. I tried with this code

```
const CustomText = (props) => {
    const text1 = props.str1.split(' ');
    const text2 = props.str2.split(' ');
    return <Text>{text1.map(text => {
      if (!text.includes(// here i should compare with other text)) {
        return <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>{text} </Text>;
      }
      return `${text} `;
    })}</Text>;
}
```

I dont knwo how to map this two string to compare each other . Thanks for helping ...

Comment: This is kind of a complex thing to do; use a [diff library](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=diff) for this.

Comment: @ChrisG whether [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff) will work with react-native

Comment: Luckily the fact that you're using react-native is completely irrelevant; it's a library that essentially compares two strings; it doesn't know or care that it is called in the context of a react-native app. You can use it in an Angular app, or node app, or wherever; as long as the environment supports JS modules. Think of it like `Math.sqrt(x)`, a function that is also completely indifferent to all that.

Comment: @ChrisG do you have any example of that how it will be used in react-native :) ? Thank you again !

Comment: Here's example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-panini-cogdo?file=/src/App.js